# Problem on layer_rescaling() on tensorflow/keras

Tags: r, keras, conv-neural-network, keras-layer

The keras package in R  `layer_rescaling()` just returns back this error:

> "Error in require_tf_version("2.6", "layer_rescaling()") : Tensorflow
> version >=2.6 required to use layer_rescaling()"

But, my keras package is already updated (2.9.0). I found the source code of keras as this:

```
layer_rescaling <-
function(object, scale, offset = 0, ...)
{
  require_tf_version("2.6", "layer_rescaling()")
  args <- capture_args(match.call(), ignore = "object")
  create_layer(keras$layers$Rescaling, object, args)
}
```

Btw, we use `layer_rescaling()` when creating a (convolutional) neural network for images. Specifically, the `layer_rescaling()` will rescale image inputs e.g. whose values are originally in the [0, 255] range to the [0, 1] range.

I think there is a problem with that source code, and I believe creating my own function for rescaling tensors will solve this problem. Or could there be a better way to solve this?

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data and code using `dput`?

Comment: You need to update keras/tensorflow to the latest version. Run `keras::install_keras()`

Comment: Edited: I apologize that I posted the wrong source code. I didn't know what had happened.

Comment: @Quinten 'layer_rescaling()' code itself does not work when applied in the environment.

Comment: @t-kalinowski keras version is updated (2.9.0).

Answer (score 1):

There are two version numbers to be aware of here: the R package version, `packageVersion("keras")`, and the Python module R is loading, `tensorflow::tf_config()`.

That error message says you need to update the Python module. You can update it by calling `keras::install_keras()`.